# How to convert http to https API URL deployed in AWS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, api, flask

I have deployed a Python Flask based app in AWS. It is running fine on `http://<ip>`. I need to convert this to https. I have sent request for admin to enable port `443` for https.

Will that automatically make my app to https or do I need to install or setup something else to make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choices for this;

**Use `ACM` (Easiest?!):**

if you're using AWS loadbalancers, you can create a certificate using `ACM` service and assign it to your loadbalancer and modify your `Target Groups` in EC2 panel.

If you are using `cloudfront`, you can also configure your `SSL/TLS` there. (Not changing the loadbalancer and target groups). It will work as an upper layer.

**Use other certificate providers excluding `AWS ACM`:**

You can setup something like `Lets Encrypt` or use `Cloudflare` services.

Note: it really depends on how your cloud stack currently is, you maybe be only deploying on EC2 Server and having Nginx configured and having everything else done outside of AWS with other services or you can have Lets Encrypt certificate on your `ALB`.
This post just gives you some keywords, you can search and see exact instruction/tutorial for every solutions.